# Spring Insight and STS

Tags: spring-tool-suite, spring-insight

I built an app and deployed to a newly made tcServer instance with the insight template.
The app runs fine (can start/stop in STS), and I can surf to the insight app (.../insight).

Insight's 'Browse Resources' and 'Recent Activity' windows are empty, so I'm assuming I need to somehow configure insight to see the local deployed app?

I was assuming that since I successfully deployed my app using STS, and I have STS controlling the tcServer instance, that Insight would automatically 'see' my app.

What am I missing?

Comment: Insight does not display apps in Chrome, works in Firefox